# Maximum number of iterations (in function “homals” in R) and transformation nonlinear data to linear data

Tags: r, pca, data-transformation, large-data

is there anyone who knows what does "maximal number of iterations" can mean in nonlinear PCA (in "homals" function in R) and how to transform nonlinear data to linear data (in R software or in generally)? Thank you really a lot in advance.

PS: I have a really large sample of data (9 variables with millions of observations) and I am not able to run it (for "homals" function - I need nonlinear PCA) in R on the university computer, so maybe with small number of iterations I can run it, but I am not sure if the results will be meaningful.

PS2: Regarding to transformation I suppose that after transformation I can use classical PCA, Factor Analysis, etc.

Comment: I'm just supposing (I'm not R user, I'm familiar with HOMALS outside R) that you may be dealing with too many distinct values (such as continuous variables). Note that techniques such as HOMALS need discretized variables. So try to bin your data reasonably (say, up to 30 values). Or use a random subset of the data for HOMALS, you will be able afterwards to transform all the millions of observations because you will be given the coefficients.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your reaction, but the problem is that my sample of data (millions of observations) is "small" sample of my data set and I can't reduce it, because there is some threshold for stable correlation coefficent between the variables, which is reached only with this sample (millions of observations) and which I need.